# Open a video file and play it from a specified time with batch

Tags: batch-file

How can i make a .bat file which opens a video file and playing it from a specified time?
for Example:

```
set /p path = Path:
set /p time = Time:
::Somehow open the video at the time::
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is quite easy but you must use VLC media player.
Here is the code.

```
@echo off
set /p way=Path_with_extension:
set /p clk=Time_to_resume_from:
vlc.exe  %ppp%  --start-time %clk%
```

The variable `way` should be enclosed in inverted commas and must contain full path with file name and extension. eg, "C:/Users/Desktop/Fifa.mp4"

The variable `clk` should contain time in seconds.